# Missing mandatory unique key field error in SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, apache-poi, solrj

I've this issue in my project. I read my .xlsx excel file using Apache Poi and I want to index them in my Solr core. I use SolrInputDocument to index reading file. Here is my java codes

```
package org.solr;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery.ORDER;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.UpdateResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

public class PoiJava {
    private static final String fileName="C:\\Users\\FTK1187\\Desktop\\E-Archive - Copy\\TableArchive.xlsx";

    public static void main(String Args[]) throws SolrServerException {
        List dataList=getArchiveData();

    }

    private static List getArchiveData() throws SolrServerException {
        List dataList =new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream excelFile=null;
        try {
            excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            String urlString="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore";
            SolrClient solr=new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
            SolrInputDocument document=new SolrInputDocument();
            if(!document.isEmpty())
            {
                solr.deleteByQuery("*");
                solr.commit();
            }

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
                    //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0
                    if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        //System.out.println(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                        for(int i=0;i<currentRow.getLastCellNum();i++)
                        {
                            if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==1)
                            {
                                document.addField("NameAdded", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==2)
                            {
                                document.addField("DateAdded", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==3)
                            {
                                document.addField("NameModified", "");
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==4)
                            {
                                document.addField("DateModified", "");
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==5)
                            {
                                document.addField("strSO", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==6)
                            {
                                document.addField("strCust", "");
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==7)
                            {
                                document.addField("strOperator", "");
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==8)
                            {
                                document.addField("PackName", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==9)
                            {
                                document.addField("DocName", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==10)
                            {
                                document.addField("DocType", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==11)
                            {
                                document.addField("extType", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==12)
                            {
                                document.addField("FileName", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==13)
                            {
                                document.addField("FilePath", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==14)
                            {
                                document.addField("NameDeleted", "");
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==15)
                            {
                                document.addField("DateDeleted", "");
                            }
                            else if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==16)
                            {
                                document.addField("intRev", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                        }


                    } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        //System.out.println(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        for(int k=0;k<currentRow.getLastCellNum();k++)
                        {
                            if(currentCell.getColumnIndex()==0)
                            {
                                document.addField("id", currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    UpdateResponse response=solr.add(document);
                    solr.commit();

                }
                //System.out.println();
                System.out.println(document.getField("id"));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

So when I'm running my project it gives me this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:610)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:152)
    at org.solr.PoiJava.getArchiveData(PoiJava.java:148)
    at org.solr.PoiJava.main(PoiJava.java:33)
```

When I'm indexing files using SimplePostTool there is not error like that but I want to update my core in my web page.

Comment: check the document prepared by you..does it have id field every it is been created and posted to solr...

Comment: I checked it and it has id field... `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>` this is in my schema.xml

Answer (score 2):

You probably have in your schema a field set as the unique key like this:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

The problem is that when you upload a doc, in this case via Apache POI, you are not sending a value for that unique field.

You have a couple options:

1. If you do have a field that will be unique, use it. For example, with a copyField option like:

```html
<copyField source="excel_guaranteed_unique" dest="id"/>
```

2. As you have the actual document, you could just add a UUID to the "id" field.
3. Create a unique field like a UUID updating your RequestHandlder, like this:

```html
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid" >
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    </processor>
    ...
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
...    
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

You also need to update the extract handler:

```
 <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
              startup="lazy"
              class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
<lst name="defaults">
  ...
  <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: First of all thank u for your answer. I did option 2 and it gives me  error like that `unknown UpdateRequestProcessorChain: uuid`

Comment: I updated the answer to use the uuid updated in the extract handler

Comment: I updated extract handler but it gives me first error `Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id` :(

Comment: Your java code sets the "id" in some condition document.addField("id", currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
Have you tried setting it always with a UUID of your own?

Comment: No, I didn't also I don't know how I'm doing it.

Comment: Also I do not want to create an 'id` field automatically, I want to index the' id` file from the excel file instead of solr id.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You want to use your own ID but your code says that there is no guarantee the ID will be present (if statement). If you make it mandatory, it has to be present. You could do a hybrid approach, use you ID when present, otherwise create one. Just make sure they are unique.

Comment: I'll explain to you now what I want. In my .xlsx file there is `id` field but it's starting for example 350 and it's increasing every data until last data. I want to index this `id` field data in my solr core like other fields. In the if statement I'm checking,is the reading data cell equals column index because my id field is in the first column in .xlsx file. Sorry my bad english. I hope I can expalin it to you better.

Comment: There is no problem when I'm updating SimplePostTool but I want to update it in web page using SolrJ.

Comment: What is the output of " System.out.println(document.getField("id"));" when you get the error?

Comment: There is just the error message in output. I tried another method in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294389/document-is-missing-mandatory-uniquekey-error-in-solrj-using-contentstreamupdate) But I can't do it again. :(

Comment: Before you call "solr.add(document);" can you print the document? See what you are sending?

Comment: I write this code `System.out.println(document.values());` and it gives me this `[]` . I guess it's not adding values in document.

Comment: OK, so that is why you get the error. You need to debug that code or set some log lines. It may not be even getting in where you assume it is getting in.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your effort. I hope it will be get fixed. I must be fixed :)